# Using Promise and await instead of then()

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, apple-musickit-js

I'm using MusicKit-JS and while this code works I don't know if there's another way of writing it.

The music methods themselves all return `__awaiter(...)`.

Is there a way to write this using promises? I don't know much about them so couldn't get it working using promises.

```
music.stop()
    .then(function () {
        music.setQueue({})
            .then(function () {
                music.setQueue({ song: id })
                    .then(function () {
                        music.play()
                    })
            })
    });
```

Comment: [Aren't promises just callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22539815)

Comment: it's already written using promises

Comment: Check the last code block in this answer for a way with await: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39458285/572644

Comment: It's not clear from your question: Is the code you've shown working and you just don't like the nesting? Or is the code you've shown *not* working? Separately: What's `__awaiter(...)`? The documentation should tell you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Afaik, `__awaiter` is part of transpiled code, the classic coroutine runner to be used with promise-yielding generator functions, and probably won't be documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these functions are all returning promises, you can wrap it in an `async` function and then use `await` and then get rid of the deep nesting:

```
async function run() {
    await music.stop();
    await music.setQueue({});
    await music.setQueue({song: id});
    await music.play();
}

run().then(() => {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is declare your functions async. Then you will be able to use await

```
async function() {
await music.stop();
//    .then(function () {
await        music.setQueue({})
//            .then(function () {
await                music.setQueue({ song: id })
//                    .then(function () {
                        music.play()
                    })
            })
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*declare your functions async*"? Why the plural? There's only one function in your code snippet.